# How do I get the max value of the sum of rows using case

Tags: php, mysql

I have a result portal where results are entered based on individual subject per term.
I need to get the class highest score, average score, and minimum score per subject from the sum of three terms ( 1 academic year)

My code gets each of the subjects per term for each student but I need to get the highest, average, and lowest score after adding the three terms for each subject

My Query

```
SELECT results.subjects,
    MAX(CASE WHEN results.term = 'First' THEN results.examTotal END) 'First'
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN results.term = 'Second' THEN results.examTotal END) 'Second'
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN results.term = 'Third' THEN results.examTotal END) 'Third'
FROM results 
WHERE studId = '".$RegNo."' 
GROUP BY   results.subjects
ORDER BY results.subjects ASC
```

I expect to have a table

```
+-----+-------+--------+-----+----------+---------+---------+-------+
+Sub  + First + Second +Third+(Total/3) + Highest + Average + Lowest+
+-----+-------+--------+-----+----------+---------+---------+-------+
+ Eng +  79   +  80    +  67 +  75.33   +   80    +  60     +  45   +
+-----+-------+--------+-----+----------+---------+---------+-------+
+Maths+   60  +  77    + 73  +   70     +   90    +  60     +  40   +
+-----+-------+--------+-----+----------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the columns you need with your query, except `(Total/3)` for which is better to use an outer query to calculate it:

```
SELECT
  t.subjects, t.First, t.Second, t.Third,
  round((t.First + t.Second + t.Third) / 3.0, 1) `(Total/3)`,
  t.Highest, t.Average, t.Lowest
FROM (
    SELECT 
      subjects,
      MAX(CASE WHEN term = 'First' THEN examTotal END) First,
      MAX(CASE WHEN term = 'Second' THEN examTotal END) Second,
      MAX(CASE WHEN term = 'Third' THEN examTotal END) Third,
      MAX(examTotal) Highest, 
      MIN(examTotal) Lowest,
      AVG(examTotal) Average
    FROM results 
    WHERE studId = '".$RegNo."' 
    GROUP BY subjects
) t
ORDER BY t.subjects ASC
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But this code gives the highest, lowest and average of the student whose result is displayed. I need the highest score in that subject in the said class

Comment: `GROUP BY subjects` gives highest lowest and average of subjects. What is class? There is no such column in your question or your code.

Comment: Sorry, May be I have issues with my presentation here but let me explain what I want to achieve. Each student belongs to a class and offers different subjects and has a score for that subject, Also there is always a best student in each subject in each class.
Now I am generating a result for each student and I have a column for the best score in individual subject. So I have tried to get this but am stuck. I have two separate queries that do these things separately. I will post them below

Comment: This generates the individual result
    <pre>SELECT results.subjects,
     MAX(CASE WHEN results.term = 'First' THEN results.examTotal END) 'First'
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN results.term = 'Second' THEN results.examTotal END) 'Second'
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN results.term = 'Third' THEN results.examTotal END) 'Third'
     FROM results 
     WHERE studId = '101001' AND resClass='JSS 1' AND acadYr='2018/2019' AND arm='Beryl'  
     GROUP BY  results.subjects
     ORDER BY results.subjects ASC
    </pre>

Comment: This generates the max sum per subject SELECT subjects, MAX(sumExamTotal) AS Highest, MIN(sumExamtotal) AS Lowest, AVG(sumExamtotal) AS Average
FROM 
(SELECT studId,resClass,arm,subjects,SUM(examTotal) AS sumExamTotal 
FROM results
WHERE acadYr='2018/2019' AND resClass='JSS 1' AND arm='Beryl' 
GROUP BY studId,subjects) results
GROUP BY subjects;